# How to create single error handler for multiple catch that are just doing same thing at multiple place and add that error handler inside another file?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I don't have much knowledge of exception.

I have two files `task.cpp`, `main.cpp`. Inside `task.cpp` file, I have a lot `try/catch` statements. I want to remove all the generic handlers for things like `...`, `std::exception` etc., they are just printing the error, and I want to create just a single error handler of this kind and reside it inside `main.cpp`. How can I do it ?

These are some part of `task.cpp` &  `main.cpp` file.

I want to remove `catch (...)`  , `catch (Exception const& _exception)  from`  `task.cpp` file as they are used at multiple steps and create repetitive code

```
        try
        {
            if (!stack.parseAndAnalyze(src.first, src.second))
                successful = false;
            else
                stack.optimize();
        }
        catch (Exception const& _exception)
        {
            serr() << "Exception in assembler: " << boost::diagnostic_information(_exception) << endl;
            return false;
        }
        catch (std::exception const& _e)
        {
            serr() <<
                "Unknown exception during compilation" <<
                (_e.what() ? ": " + string(_e.what()) : ".") <<
                endl;
            return false;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            serr() << "Unknown exception in assembler." << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }



   if (_language != yul::AssemblyStack::Language::Ewasm && _targetMachine == yul::AssemblyStack::Machine::Ewasm)
        {
            try
            {
                stack.translate(yul::AssemblyStack::Language::Ewasm);
                stack.optimize();
            }
            catch (Exception const& _exception)
            {
                serr() << "Exception in assembler: " << boost::diagnostic_information(_exception) << endl;
                return false;
            }
            catch (std::exception const& _e)
            {
                serr() <<
                    "Unknown exception during compilation" <<
                    (_e.what() ? ": " + string(_e.what()) : ".") <<
                    endl;
                return false;
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                serr() << "Unknown exception in assembler." << endl;
                return false;
            }

            sout() << endl << "==========================" << endl;
            sout() << endl << "Translated source:" << endl;
            sout() << stack.print() << endl;
        }


        try
        {
            object = stack.assemble(_targetMachine);
            object.bytecode->link(m_options.linker.libraries);
        }
        catch (Exception const& _exception)
        {
            serr() << "Exception while assembling: " << boost::diagnostic_information(_exception) << endl;
            return false;
        }
        catch (std::exception const& _e)
        {
            serr() << "Unknown exception during compilation" << (
                _e.what() ? ": " + string(_e.what()) : "."
            ) << endl;
            return false;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            serr() << "Unknown exception while assembling." << endl;
            return false;
        }
```

And catch inside `main.cpp` file like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        setDefaultOrCLocale();
        solidity::frontend::CommandLineInterface cli(cin, cout, cerr);
        if (!cli.parseArguments(argc, argv) || !cli.readInputFiles() || !cli.processInput() || !cli.actOnInput())
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
    catch (boost::exception const& _exception || Exception const& _exception || InternalCompilerError const& _exception
        || smtutil::SMTLogicError const& _exception)
    {
        cerr << "Uncaught exception" << boost::diagnostic_information(_exception) << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& _e)
    {
        cerr() << "Uncaught exception" << (_e.what() ? ": " + string(_e.what()) : ".") << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception const& _exc)
    {
        cerr() << string("Failed to import AST: ") << _exc.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cerr << "Uncaught exception" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like `void run(std::function<void()> f) { try { f()} catch (/*..*/) { /*..*/} }`?

Comment: Why do you catch them in your library? If your code is "normal" i.e. non concurrent/async, then you can just try catch in your main. Please post a [mre]